# Not able to install Service fabric SDK 4.1.409 to Windows 10 laptop

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

While installing Service fabric SDK 4.1.409 to my laptop through Web platform installer 5.1. it is throwing below error.

> 6/3/2020 5:12:45 AM,Info,6/3/2020 10:42:45 AM Running Process: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\MicrosoftServiceFabricAutoextractor.exe /L "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric" /E /Y with timeout 01:00:00
>   6/3/2020 5:12:48 AM,Error,Unable to extract exe. ExitCode: -1073741502

I have followed microsoft installation step from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started#sdk-installation-only) link but no luck.

Comment: are you running Win10 64bit or 32?

Answer (score 0):

This issues might be with my company policy imposed to system or registry corrupt . 
solution: I resolved this by below step.
1.Resetting windows.
2.Service fabric sdk installation
3.Visual studio 2017/19 installation.